# What exersise routine would I be able to do which would prepare me for pre-employment physical assessment outline below?

Tags: cardio, flexibility, bellyfat

I have just been given the info on a pre-employment physical assessment for a job I am looking at. There are 5 components and I can see obvious answers to achieving some of the goals but some are going to be a little bit challenging.
**Stage 1:** is a skin fold test- Not much I can do about this one as I presume the result will be related to my prep on the other parts of the assessment. If anyone has idea on how this can be improved quickly I would appreciate it.
**Stage 2:** Is a flexibility test based on reach. For this I am making sure I stretch properly when i exercise and trying to do stretches through the day as often as possible.
**Stage 3:** A cardio assessment using a Monark bike test. 3 minute warm up, increase resistance at 3 minutes then again at 6 minutes then resistance decreases at 9 minute for the return heart rate to be assessed. I'm not sure what the what a Monark bike is. I am also working away from home and have no access to a bike, what other solutions to increase the cardio while I'm away could I do that when I do have to jump on a bike I can be at least some part prepared.
**Stage 4:** Push ups 5 x standing at a wall the 5 arms at shoulder length but knees on the ground, 5 arms shoulder length apart but coming off the toes, 5 with hands together and fingers forming the shape of a diamond and the 5 with the same hand position but with feet up on a step. I can do the first 3 easy enough but struggle a bit with the hands together style (and haven't even added the feet on the step trick in yet).
**Step 5:** Sit ups 5 x wrist to knees, 5 x hands on chest and raising up, 5 x hands on forehead then 5 with hands behind the ears. I haven't done sit ups for years because I thought (wrongly I guess) that they were no longer used very much as an exercise.
Well its a long question with probably a heap of answers so even if you have thoughts on just part of this process I would appreciate the feedback.
And now for Macca's Quarter Pounder with cheese and a thick shake. Apparently these are important food groups or so my teenagers tell me.

Comment: When is the interview/physical? You may not have enough time to do anything that would make a difference.

Comment: Define 'pre-employment'?  Is this an assessment you have to pass or you already have the job and it's just an assessment?  Ending up assigned to perform tasks you're not ready for because you "trained to the test" to get better marks in a few arbitrary measures might have long term consequences?

Comment: Monarch Bike http://www.monarkexercise.se/default.asp?PageID=677

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your test is in the fairly near future, you aren't going to be able to do much for your body fat percentage (i.e. the skin-fold test) or your general strength and conditioning.

However, the body responds to very specific training. By far the best bang-for-the buck would be to simply practice stages 2-5 as closely to the testing conditions as you can. Muscle memory will go a long way towards improved results - even a few runs through the test will make a difference. That way you aren't learning the movements while being tested.

I would also suggest recording results from your self tests so that you can see where you are improving, and how far away you are from passing marks (if you know what these are). If you don't know what passing marks are, you may want to focus on those stages which are improving the fastest, since those are where you have quick, easy gains.